# Process Subscriptions and One time payments together using Paypal

Tags: reactjs, paypal

we are using Paypal to process payments on our website. We offer monthly subscriptions to our customers and transfer a certain amount of credits to their accounts according to their purchased subscriptions. But the customer can also purchase add-ons for some extra credits which are one-time payments.

We have worked with recurring and one-time payments separately using "react-paypal-button-v2" react package.

Subscription

```
<PayPalButton
            createSubscription={(data, details) => createSubscription(data, details)}
            onApprove={(data, details) => onApprove(data, details)}
            onError={(err) => onError(err)}
            catchError={(err) => catchError(err)}
            onCancel={(err) => onCancel(err)}
            options={{
                clientId: "",
                vault: true
            }}
/>
```

One-time payment

```
<PayPalButton
            createOrder={(data, details) => createOrder(data, details)}
            onApprove={(data, details) => onApprove(data, details)}
            onError={(err) => onError(err)}
            catchError={(err) => catchError(err)}
            onCancel={(err) => onCancel(err)}
            options={{
                clientId: "",
                vault: true
            }}
/>
```

Is there a way to handle both of these in one transaction, so customers can purchase subscriptions and add-ons together?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`react-paypal-button-v2` is not an official package, you might have an easier time with `react-paypal-js`. However, either may need to be extended to be able to load two SDKs with different namespaces, which is what's usually required for showing working one time payments and subscription buttons on the same page.

Here is how to do that with HTML/JS (no react code):

```html
<script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=test&intent=capture"></script>
<script>
    paypal.Buttons().render('body');
</script>
 
<script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=test&vault=true&intent=subscription" data-namespace="paypalSubscriptions"></script>
<script>
    paypalSubscriptions.Buttons({
        style: { label:'subscribe' },
        createSubscription: function(data, actions) {
            return actions.subscription.create({ 'plan_id': '' });
        }
    }).render('body');
</script>
```

Note the use of `data-namespace` for the second script and button.

---

As for processing such payments in the **same** button/transaction, it's not possible other than if you were to have your createSubscription function **override** the `plan_id` to include whatever one-time amounts you want to charge.

To override `plan_id` values, specify an additional inline `plan` object for the [subscription create](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/subscriptions/v1/#subscriptions-create-request-body).